# How to find out if there is any change in the values between the top two rows of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

| ID | MeterPointID | Value1 | Value2 | CreatedUtc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4028 | 123 | 241 | 2021-01-29 09:58:24.977 |
| 2 | 4028 | 456 | 341 | 2021-01-29 09:56:39.517 |

In the above table both the rows are identified by same meter point id, that means values for second row has been entered before approx. 4 minutes from the first row and there are change in values of Both the rows in these 4 minutes. So, Here I just want a parameter needs to set true or false based on if there is any change in values. If yes then set the parameter to true else false. Please help me with the suitable answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your dbms

Comment: sql server @D-Shih

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Many DBMSs support both OLAP functions (those with `OVER(...)` ) and the `NVL()` (synonyms for that: `ISNUL()` or `IFNULL()` ) function that returns the first parameter if it is not NULL , otherwise the second. If your DBMS does both, try this:

```
WITH
-- your input, thanks for providing it in a COPY-PASTE-able format ...
indata(ID,MeterPointID,Value1,Value2,CreatedUtc) AS (
          SELECT 1,4028,123,241,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-29 09:58:24.977'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,4028,456,341,TIMESTAMP '2021-01-29 09:56:39.517'
)
SELECT
  *
, (
    NVL(value1<>LAG(value1) OVER (PARTITION BY meterpointid ORDER BY createdutc),FALSE)
 OR NVL(value1<>LAG(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY meterpointid ORDER BY createdutc),FALSE)
 ) AS has_changed
FROM indata;
 ID | MeterPointID | Value1 | Value2 |       CreatedUtc        | has_changed
----+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------------+-------------
  2 |         4028 |    456 |    341 | 2021-01-29 09:56:39.517 | f
  1 |         4028 |    123 |    241 | 2021-01-29 09:58:24.977 | t
```

Comment: SQL Server uses `ISNULL` not `NVL`, any case `LAG` has a "default" parameter

Comment: The default parameter of `LAG(<expression>,<row_distance>,<default>)` needs to be a constant in most DBMSs; I had tried that bit at first, but two of my DBMSs complained , so I resorted to `NVL()`, `ISNULL()` or `IFNULL()`, the three synonym functions widely supported.

Comment: [Quote:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "*default* can be a column, subquery, or other expression, but it cannot be an analytic function. *default* must be type-compatible with *scalar_expression*. So you can use anything you like in there. You should check up the DBMS that is tagged before you answer

Comment: I stand corrected . Although it wasn't tagged [SQL-Server] when I formulated my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want value `true` or `false` if the maximum and minimum values are different, then you can use:

```
select MeterPointID,
       (case when count(*) = 2 and
                  max(CreatedUtc) < dateadd(minute, 4, min(CreatedUtc)) and
                  (min(value1) <> max(value1) or min(value2) <> max(value2)
                  )
             then 'true' else 'false'
        end) as change_within_4_minutes
from t
group by MeterPointID;
```